# How to make Virtualbox serial work on Windows 7 guest

Tags: virtualbox

I have a Ubuntu 10.10 (64bit) hosts with a physical serial port, now I want to connect that physical port into virtual serial port on windows 7 guest, so I can transfer data from the win7 guest to the Ubuntu host via serial line.

In the Windows 7 Guest setting I use the following configuration :

```
Port number : COM1
Port Mode : Host Device
Port/File Path : /dev/ttyS0
```

But when I get into windows 7 ... There's no COM port was detected ?_?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Has the "Enable Serial Port" check-box been checked off within the settings for the VM?

Comment: I've already checked !

Comment: How the "Guest Additions" for the VM (just covering the basics)?

Comment: I've already installed !